# Change local linux password when joined to Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, passwords

I have a linux box:
Linux vuappserver 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Mon Oct 3 04:15:24 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

I use SMB + windbind to join to and Active Directory

But right now I try to add a local user:

useradd test

but when I try to change the password I receive this error:

root@server:/home/vu# passwd test
Current Kerberos password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged

I checked the permissions of this files:

-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 1350 Apr  5 23:17 /etc/passwd
-rw-r----- 1 0 42 941 Apr  5 23:17 /etc/shadow

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

by default pam_krb5.so set the "minimun_uid" to 1000 in /etc/pam.d/common-*
e.g.:

```
password    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
```

my user had uid=1001 and according to the default setup, kerberos took control (bad thing). In the other hand, the mapping for my AD users was in a higher range (/etc/samba/smb.conf):

```
idmap config * : range = 10000-40000
```

So, I adjusted the "minimun_uid" in /etc/pam.d/common-* to 10000, and now I'm happy :-)

Comment: You can change all pam files at once: `sudo sed -i 's/minimum_uid=1000\b/minimum_uid=10000/g' /etc/pam.d/common-*`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're in a Windows domain, your authentication configuration (most probably /etc/pam.d/common-auth and /etc/pam.d/passwd) is pointing that to change a password, it must be synchronized with the domain (via Kerberos/LDAP).
You can instruct the **passwd** command to change a local account by specifying which accounts repository/authentication realm you would like to change:

```
passwd -r files account_name
```

Check the man page for passwd on the -r option.